# ASP.Net Core 5 MVC Bootstrap Render Div When Screen Smaller Than X Width

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am creating an ASP.Net Core 5 App with Bootstrap 5. I want to conditionally render the Header elements based on screen width.

[image]

This is the header when the browser is larger, like on a laptop.

Right now, everything collapses into the bootstrap hamburger menu. What I want to happen is for the Hello David, Logout, and Cart Info button to be placed to the right of the My Shopping Cart Logo, and for the Home, Privacy, and Search to go to the hamburger menu. Here is the current view when everything is collapsed.

[image]

And what I want to accomplish is something like

[image]

But now that I am looking at it, maybe I will get rid of the Log Out button, and make logout part of the Hello David drop down.

So in order to accomplish something like this, I need to check for when the screen is smaller than x width...Whenever Bootstrap collapses everything down.

I have done lots of Googling, and I see posts about media queries, but I get the sense that media queries are for something like React or Angular.

How would I accomplish this in ASP.Net Core 5 MVC? Here is my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index"><img src="@(Configuration.GetValue<string>("StorageContainerURL"))/store-logo.png" ) 
                                                                                  class="img-fluid" style="max-height:75px;width:auto" alt="Alternate Text" /></a>

        @*I want to render*@

        @*
        <partial name="_Identity.cshtml" /> @*This is the Hello David and Logout Button

        <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("ShoppingCartSummary") @*This is the Shopping Cart Button"
        </ul>
        *@

        @*if the screen is < X width*@

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                </li>

                @if (!User.IsInRole("Seller"))
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="EditProfile">Become a Seller</a>
                    </li>
                }

            </ul>

            <form class="d-flex" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Filter">
                <input name="searchString" class="form-control me-1" type="search" placeholder="Search for a product..." aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>

            <partial name="_Identity.cshtml" /> @*This is the Hello David and Logout Button*@

            <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("ShoppingCartSummary") @*This is the Shopping Cart Button*@
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Edit: I figured it out.
I wanted to show the answer, but I do not want to take credit for the answer.

This will only be visible on xs, sm, and md screens.

```
<div class="d-block d-lg-none">
```

This will only be visible on lg and larger screens.

```
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">
```

This is applicable to Bootstrap 5.

See [Bootstrap 5 Hiding Elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

Comment: try add class "hidden-xs"

Comment: I tried hidden-xs and it does not work. Could you possibly demonstrate it for me? I wrapped the identity partial in <div class="hidden-xs">

Comment: sorry.. bootstrap-5 need "d-none d-sm-block"